# Convert a Method to C# source Code

Tags: c#, reflection, code-generation, reflector

I am writing a fairly simple code gen tool, and I need the ability to convert MSIL (or MethodInfo) objects to their C# source.  I realize Reflector does a great job of this, but it has the obnoxious "feature" of being UI only.

I know I could just generate the C# strings directly, using string.Format to insert the variable portions, but I'd really prefer to be able to generate methods programatically (e.g. a delegate or MethodInfo object), then pass those methods to a writer which would convert them to C#.

It seems a little silly that the System libraries make it so easy to go from a C# source code string to a compiled (and executable) method at runtime, but impossible to go from an object to source code--even for simple things.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This [add-in for Reflector](http://www.codeplex.com/FileGenReflector) lets you output to a file, and it is possible to run Reflector from the command line. It's probably simpler to get that to do what you want than to roll your own decompiler.

[Anakrino](http://legacy.saurik.com/net/exemplar/) is another decompiler with a command line option, but it hasn't been updated since .NET 1.1. It's open source, though, so you might be able to base your solution on it.

Answer (score 0):

The code generators which I wrote as part of our application use `String.Format`, and although I am not entirely happy with `String.Format` (Lisp macros beat it any time of the day) it does the job all right. The C# compiler is going to re-check all your generated methods anyway, so you gain nothing by round-tripping through Reflection.Emit and the (still unwritten) MSIL-to-C# decompiler.

PS: why not use CodeDOM if you want to use something heavyweight?

Comment: hi. The CodeDom useful when generate code but it is not support parse from source code to CodeDom object.

Comment: @DavidDao You can use Roslyn for that.